# Spring Data query on field List of string

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have a column like this

```
@Column(name = "delivery_categories")
@Convert(converter = HibernateStringConverter.class)
private List<String> deliveryCategories;
```

and this is my converter

```
@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> list) {
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty())
        return String.join(",", list);
    else
        return "";
}

@Override
public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
    if (joined != null && !joined.isEmpty())
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
    else
        return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

I use spring data for queries,
when I use the below query

```
findAllByFeedbackTypeAndValidUserTypeAndDeliveryCategoriesInAndEvaluationTypeInAndStatus(
        FeedbackType feedbackType,
        UserType userType,
        List<String> deliveryCategories,
        List<EvaluationType> evaluationType, String status)
```

I get this error

> Parameter value [BIKE] did not match expected type [java.util.List (n/a)]

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Did you add the `@Converter` annotation to the converter class ?

Comment: @Lookslikeitsnot yes I added it before